# Checking for elements in list

Tags: python, list, search, element

I want to do function which will have list with elements inside (strings)
Then I have second long string example:

```
<a href="https://ertfwetwer" target="_blank">[Nerve Center]</a>
```

and I want to check if certain element from my list is inside that string.
And if it is, I want to store that element in some var.

Example

```
List = ['href','a']
```

Check if "href" is inside second string
*yes it is*

store '`href`' in some var.

I want it to work just like this. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Look up "if" conditional and how to add to a list?

Comment: What if I want to make it "broader" check if element is inside string store that element in var, without specifying that element

Comment: You will have to clarify what you mean -- as in post what you are doing now and what you wish it was doing or what it's failing on

Comment: I have long string from page source, and I want to see if .jpg or .png or .swf or .wbm or...... is inside if it is I want to store it in some var as str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Main approach for checking elements of a list in a string is :

```
s= '''<a href="https://ertfwetwer" target="_blank">[Nerve Center]</a>'''
my_list=['href','a']

   def checker(mylist, my_string)
     new = list()

     for i in mylist:
        if i in my_string: # if elements is in string (you can check only special elements )
            print i ,'is in string'
            new.append(i) #storing result to new list 

   checker (my_list, s)
```

output :

```
href is in string
a is in string
```

But because you say *I have long string from page source, and I want to see if .jpg or .png or .swf or .wbm or...... is inside if it is I want to store it in some var as str*

So you want use regex to your code for finding all .jpg or more foramtting in your long string ! let's assume you have

```
s= '''<a href="https://ertfwetwer" target="_blank">[Nerve Center]   
myname.jpg another.pdf mynext.xvf </a>'''
```

so you want to check `.jpg` and another formated

```
my_list=['.jpg','.pdf']

for i in my_list:
 if i in s:
  print i ,'is in string'
```

You can also find their name :

```
import re
s= '''<a next.pdf href="https://ertfwetwer" target="_blank">[Nerve Center] myfile.jpg another.pdf </a>'''

 re.findall(r'([^\s]+).jpg|([^\s]+).pdf',s)
```

output:

```
[('myfile', ''), ('', 'another')]
```

Or even

```
for i in  re.findall(r'([^\s]+).jpg|([^\s]+).pdf',s):
    for j in i:
        print j.strip(' ')



next
myfile
another
```